# Style of list numbers not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a list where I have styled the numbers of the list to look different from the content of the list itself. E.g

```
1 Monday
2 Tuesday
```

where the numbers 1 and 2 are styled green and the content is styled white. This works in Chrome but for some reason IE does not pick up the styles and styles the numbers as white as well. Here is the styles for the list

```
 dropdown-menu li ul { font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#cecece; list-    style-type:decimal; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:30px; margin-right:40px; counter-reset: item; display: table; margin-left:0; padding:0;}
.dropdown-menu li ul li { font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; margin-top: 2px; display: table-row; position:relative; list-style:none; margin:2px 0 6px 2em; margin-bottom:10px;}
.dropdown-menu li ul li:before { color:#ad0c10 !important; content:     counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item; display: table-cell; text-align:right; padding-right:10px; width:2em; top:-2px; left:-2em; margin-right:10px; color:#ad0c10 !important; }
.header { font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#ad0c10; list-style-type:decimal; margin:10px 0px 0px 40px; text-transform:uppercase; color:#ad0c10; }
.header ul li { font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#cecece; margin-top: 2px; text-transform:none; }
```

Any ideas why IE might ignore these styles ??

Comment: Add this to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Refer this page - http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2010/06/applying-color-to-ordered-list-numbers.html

Comment: If you can add your exact HTML and CSS to a jsfiddle this problem will be fixed in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not really know ***why*** part of it, but IE snaps up at `display: table-cell` on `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

Remove `display: table-cell` on your `.dropdown-menu li ul li:before` and make it simply `display: inline-block;`, and voila you will see colors in IE!

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/r9rD6/2/***

BTW: Any specific reason, you need `table-row` and `table-cell` on those list items and pseudo elements?

Comment: The reason is so that if the content for that list number is longer than one line then it wont continue the text under the number but rather under the beginning of the text

Comment: You can control that using a negative `text-indent` on the list item. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/r9rD6/3/

Comment: This works great in IE, but the text indent doesn't format the text in Chrome for some reason.

Comment: Also, I have a list within one of my lists and the text indent then indents that list to the same as it's parent

Comment: Works just fine on Chrome. I use Chrome only. Regarding your other comment, it is very difficult to do guess-work without actually seeing your entire list markup along with what you are actually after.